# async generator returned from intermediate function raising TypeError

Tags: python, python-asyncio

I've got a generator like this:

```
async def blah1(v):
  ...
  async for blah in blahblah(v):
    yield blah

async def intermediateblah(v):
  return await blah1(v)
```

And I'm trying to do a list comprehension:

```
assert [x async for x in await intermediateblah("*")] == ["a"]
```

But I'm getting this error: `TypeError: object async_generator can't be used in 'await' expression` I think my main problem is that in `intermediateblah`, I have to `await blah1` since there are some other code pieces that require me to use await.

Anyone know how I can do this list comprehension? Or just a for loop in general?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't await an async  generator, just like you do not call a plain one returned by a function.

Simply return it

```
async def intermediateblah(v):
  return blah1(v)
```